# Cannot deserialize JSONObject (inside of JSONArray) in Java Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

So, I have this method here:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getFields", produces = "application/json")
public Response getFields(@RequestParam(value = "id") int id)
```

and I have a class which extends Response.
In this class, I have defined a `JSONArray`, in which I put a `JSONObject` through a method which wraps `JSONArray.put(JSONObject obj)`.

At the end of my getRegistrationFields I return the instantiated object of the class extending Response.

This way, Spring should return the JSONArray contained in this object, and I should see it when I call "/getFields" REST method.

However, it gives me an Error 500

```
Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer
```

Is there a quick way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the next dependency (or jar:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If doesn't help, try to use Jackson **ArrayNode** and **ObjectNode** instead of JSONArray and JSONObject.

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
    Object obj = new Object();
    arrayNode.addPOJO(obj);
    arrayNode.add(mapper.createObjectNode().put("field1", "Hello Stack!"));
```

Please see the link to the doc: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/ArrayNode.html

Comment: The ArrayNode and ObjectNode did the job!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have To Accept it first as a Json Array ,then while reading its Object have to use Object Mapper.readValue ,because Json Object Still in String .

```
List<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();
JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(response);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    User usr = mapper.readValue(jsonObj.toString(), User.class);      
    list.add(usr);
}
```